# Semantic UI react grid columns order

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I have an ordered list of check boxes (this.state.columns):

1.
2.
3.
4.
5.
6.
...

and I want to display this list in two columns, but semantic ui grid it is changing the order to:

'1.'    '2.'

'3.'    '4.'

'5.'    '6.'

This is my code:

```
<Grid stackable columns={2}>
        {this.state.columns.map(
          data =>
            data.label !== ' ' && (
              <Grid.Column key={data.key}>
                <Field
                  name={data.key}
                  component={fields.field.checkbox}
                  label={data.label}
                  type="checkbox"
                  control={Checkbox}
                />
              </Grid.Column>
            )
        )}
</Grid>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? I need to be displayed like this:

'1.'     '4.'

'2.'     '5.'

'3.'     '6.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Grid can have a `Grid.Row` and this should have a `Grid.Column`.

You have defined your grid to have 2 columns; this should have your Component tree for the first 3 levels look similar to this:

`Grid` 
----`Grid.Row` 
---------`Grid.Column` (GridColumn#1) 
---------`Grid.Column` (GridColumn#2)

GridColumn#1 will contain have of the data contained in `this.state.columns`
and GridColumn#2 will contain the other half.

You can get the half for GridColumn#1 by slicing the array up to half its length and from half its length for GridColumn#2.

**Note that** you need to adjust this for cases where the array length for `this.state.columns` is odd. (in the example below, I have relied on the Javascript to convert floating point numbers to integer)

Here is one way to implement this; it could benefit from some refactoring.

```
  renderCheckboxColumns() {
    const { columns } = this.state
    const leftColumns = columns.slice(0, (columns.length + 1 )/ 2).map(
      data =>
        <Grid.Row>
          <Grid.Column>{data}</Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>
    )

    const rightColumns = columns.slice((columns.length + 1)/ 2).map(
      data =>
        <Grid.Row>
          <Grid.Column>{data}</Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>
    )

    return (
      <Grid.Row>
        <Grid.Column>
          {leftColumns}
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column>
          {rightColumns}
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid.Row>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Grid stackable columns={2}>
        {this.renderCheckboxColumns()}
      </Grid>

    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are set on using columns, but one way to solve it is to use the grid container and series of grid items of size 6.

```
<Grid container spacing={24}>
        {this.state.columns.filter(d => d.label !== ' ')
          .reduce((map, d, i) => {
            let modulo = Math.ceil(this.state.columns.length/2)
            let row = [d]
            if (i+modulo < this.state.columns.length) {
                row.push(this.state.columns[i+modulo])
            }
            map = map.concatenate(row.map(data => 
                <Grid item key={data.key} xs={6}>
                <Field
                  name={data.key}
                  component={fields.field.checkbox}
                  label={data.label}
                  type="checkbox"
                  control={Checkbox}
                />
              </Grid>))

           }, [])}
</Grid>
```